# Support additional JSON media types with Moxy

Tags: java, json, jax-rs, jersey-2.0, moxy

I am currently building a Java application with `Jersey` (JAX-RS) and `Moxy`. Everything works great, but i would also like to support `PATCH` HTTP method. I created a custom annotation for the `PATCH` method but the media type for a patch request will be `application/json-patch+json`, which for some reason i am not getting the request body

My `PATCH.java` file

```
@Target({ElementType.METHOD, ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@HttpMethod("PATCH")
@Documented
@NameBinding
public @interface PATCH {
}
```

My `TestResource.java` file

```
@Path("/tests")
public class TestResource {
    private @Context ContainerRequestContext context;

    @PATCH
    @Path("/{id}")
    @Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
    @Consumes({ "application/json-patch+json" })
    public Response patchTest(final String body) {
        Log.info("Body: " + body);
    }
}
```

I am trying to patch the resource like following

```
curl -s -H "Accept: application/json" \
        -H "Content-Type: application/json-patch+json" \
        -d '[{"op":"replace","path":"/abc","value":"xyz"}]' \
        -X PATCH http://localhost/tests/1
```

I do receive the request but the request body is not being captured. I tried it with a `POJO`, `String`, `byte[]` etc. But the `POST` and `PUT` work fine (i guess since the consuming media type is `application/json`)

Hope i got all the details in, please feel free to ask me if i am missing any details. Hope someone has run into this before

Comment: If it helps, this works fine with `jackson` as the json provider

Comment: I say if Jackson works, use it. Moxy is not your friend. I'm sure you will run into more problems in the future, aside from this one, that could be solved using Jackson. I've been through many of them.